# TSQL Internal Rate of Return (IRR) from row instead of columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a data table like this:

```
Group   ID    M0    M1    ...    M20
------------------------------------
    1    1    10    -2    ...     54
    1    2    -8    10    ...    -20
    2    6   -10    12    ...      0
    2    4    45    52    ...      0
    2    5    12   102    ...      0
```

I'm grouping my data by Group like so:

```
SELECT Group
     , round(sum(M0+M1+M2+...+M20)/count(ID),2) as profit
     , round(sum(M0),2) as M0
     , round(sum(M1),2) as M1
     , ...
     , round(sum(M20),2) as M20
FROM
    data_table
GROUP BY
    Group
```

What I need to add is IRR based on M0 to M20 columns.

I found an IRR function that looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_IRR]
  (
   @strIDs VARCHAR(8000),
   @guess DECIMAL(30,10)
  )
RETURNS DECIMAL(30, 10)
AS 
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @t_IDs TABLE (
        id INT IDENTITY(0, 1),
        value DECIMAL(30, 10)
    )
    DECLARE @strID VARCHAR(12),@sepPos INT,@NPV DECIMAL(30, 10)
    SET @strIDs = COALESCE(@strIDs + ',', '')
    SET @sepPos = CHARINDEX(',', @strIDs)
    WHILE @sepPos > 0 
      BEGIN
        SET @strID = LEFT(@strIDs, @sepPos - 1)
        INSERT INTO @t_IDs ( value ) SELECT ( CAST(@strID AS DECIMAL(20, 10)) ) WHERE ISNUMERIC(@strID) = 1
        SET @strIDs = RIGHT(@strIDs, DATALENGTH(@strIDs) - @sepPos)
        SET @sepPos = CHARINDEX(',', @strIDs)
      END

    SET @guess = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@guess, 0) <= 0 THEN 0.00001 ELSE @guess END

    SELECT @NPV = SUM(value / POWER(1 + @guess, id)) FROM @t_IDs
    WHILE @NPV > 0 
      BEGIN
        SET @guess = @guess + 0.00001
        SELECT @NPV = SUM(value / POWER(1 + @guess, id)) FROM @t_IDs
      END
    RETURN @guess
  END
```

Sample usage looks like this:

```
SELECT  dbo.ufn_IRR('-4000,1200,1410,1875,1050',0.00001)
```

But in my case I would like to avoid creating string from my columns, as this:

```
 SELECT  dbo.ufn_IRR(
    cast(round(sum([M0]), 2) AS NVARCHAR)+','
   +cast(round(sum([M1]), 2) AS NVARCHAR)+','
   +cast(round(sum([M2]), 2) AS NVARCHAR)+','
   +cast(round(sum([M3]), 2) AS NVARCHAR)+','
   +cast(round(sum([M4]), 2) AS NVARCHAR)+','
   +...+','
   +cast(round(sum([M20]), 2) AS NVARCHAR)
 ,0.00001)
```

I think it is pointless to first create a string and then inside function cut it into table.
I would like to modify IRR function so than I can pass my columns, but I don't have Idea how I should do that :/

Comment: The way I'd do it, it gets pretty complex, with Unpivot and perhaps Table variables. Must you be able to process any values from any table, or will you only be processing those specific columns from that specific table?

Comment: For now I need to process last 21 columns of that table - from Mo to M20. I'll worry in the future with universal function for. Right now only this one :)

Comment: Uh . . . Have you considered rewriting the function so it takes the arguments without parsing them?

Comment: That's an option :) So my function should take 22 arguments? 21 will be M0-M20 and last will be guess. But then I will have to call function like `irr(sum([M0]),sum([M1]),...,sum([M20]),0.00001)`. But how should I then inside my function handle all parameters? Or can I pass parameters another way? To avoid writing all columns comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_IRR]
  (
   @s0 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s1 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s2 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s3 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s4 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s5 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s6 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s7 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s8 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s9 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s10 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s11 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s12 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s13 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s14 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s15 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s16 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s17 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s18 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s19 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @s20 DECIMAL(30,10),
   @guess DECIMAL(30,10)
  )
RETURNS DECIMAL(30, 10)
AS 
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @t_IDs TABLE (
        id INT IDENTITY(0, 1),
        value DECIMAL(30, 10)
    )
    Declare @NPV DECIMAL(30, 10)

    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s0);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s1);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s2);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s3);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s4);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s5);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s6);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s7);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s8);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s9);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s10);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s11);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s12);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s13);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s14);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s15);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s16);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s17);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s18);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s19);
    INSERT INTO @t_IDs (value) values (@s20);

    SET @guess = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@guess, 0) <= 0 THEN 0.00001 ELSE @guess END

    SELECT @NPV = SUM(value / POWER(1 + @guess, id)) FROM @t_IDs
    WHILE @NPV > 0 
      BEGIN
        SET @guess = @guess + 0.00001
        SELECT @NPV = SUM(value / POWER(1 + @guess, id)) FROM @t_IDs
      END
    RETURN @guess
  END
```

And use it

```
dbo.ufn_IRR(round(sum([M0]), 2),
            round(sum([M1]), 2),
            .....
            round(sum([M20]),2),
            0.00001)
```

Comment: This is what I have in mind. I was trying to avoid such a declaration, because if I will need 80 columns then function will take 81 parameters. But I think this is my only option :)

Comment: I'll stick with this solution. It is simplest to achieve, and I can always add extra parameters to it. It would be best to have an universal function, but for now this option is good for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've updated the code to changed the guess method 
from increment (0.00001) 
to guest from 0.1 to 0.01 to 0.001

sample usage of the function is

```
select [dbo].[fn_IRR]('-21000,0,0,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00,1948.00',0.0000000001)
```

hope this help.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_IRR]
(
    @str varchar(max),
    @precision DECIMAL(30,10)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(30, 10)
AS 
BEGIN
    declare  @AdjValue decimal(30,10)
            ,@guess Decimal(30,10)
            ,@guess_new Decimal(30,10)

    Select @AdjValue = 0.1, @guess=0

    DECLARE @t_IDs TABLE (
        id INT IDENTITY(0, 1),
        value DECIMAL(30, 10)
    )
    Declare @NPV DECIMAL(30, 10)
           ,@iter_cnt int

    INSERT INTO @t_IDs 
        select * from dbo.fn_SplitString(@str,',')

    SET @guess = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@guess, 0) <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE @guess END

    SELECT @NPV = SUM(value / POWER(1 + @guess, id)) FROM @t_IDs
    WHILE ((@NPV > 0 or @AdjValue > @precision) and (isnull(@iter_cnt,0) < 8192))
    BEGIN
        SET @guess_new = @guess + @AdjValue
        SELECT @NPV = SUM(value / POWER(1 + @guess_new, id)) FROM @t_IDs
        set @iter_cnt = isnull(@iter_cnt,0) + 1
        if (@NPV > 0)
            select @guess=@guess_new
        else
            select @AdjValue=@AdjValue/10
    END
    RETURN @guess
END


Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString](
     @str nvarchar(max)
    ,@sep nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH a AS(
        SELECT CAST(0 AS BIGINT) as idx1,CHARINDEX(@sep,@str) idx2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT idx2+1,CHARINDEX(@sep,@str,idx2+1)
        FROM a
        WHERE idx2>0
    )
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,idx1,COALESCE(NULLIF(idx2,0),LEN(@str)+1)-idx1) as StrValue
    FROM a
```

Comment: It's a bit old question, but I'll check Your modification in free time, Thanks for help :)

Comment: @AlphaAU why doesn't this function return also negative IRR? Why it returns 0 for negative IRR ?

Comment: @CiucaS sorry that i didn't notice you left a comment here, but great to heard you've found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My suggested approach is...

Define an independent `table @t_IDs ( term INT, value DECIMAL )`. Before invoking `ufn_IRR()`, manually populate the `table` with `rows` `(1, M0), (2, M1) ... (n, M20)`. (Err, with my `SQL` knowledge this seems like a looping step, but perhaps `SQL-Server` can do it in one statement?) Then simply call `ufn_IRR()` with the `@guess` parameter. You first need to modify `ufn_IRR()` and discard the initial bits that split `@strIDs` into the `@t_IDs table`.

This approach has the advantage of working on data of varying sizes.

`ufn_IRR()` uses a linear root-finding method. For large or repetitive tasks, perhaps investigate other methods; the Wikipedia page on "Internal rate of return" suggests a few.

Answer (score 1):

Sketching out one way to do it.

First off, I would write a procedure to work with this one table, with the following steps:

- Create a temp table
- Populate it from the base table using an `select... unpivot...` query (converts 21 columns into a 1 column 21 row dataset)
- Run the math against the temp table

Downside is, you can only process the one table, and you have to hard-code the names of the 21 columns in the unpivot query, which is not very flexible.

Fancier step is to use create the #temp table, and then use dynamic sql to build the unpivot based on whatever columns (from whatever table) you programmatically detrmine need to be procesed.

To turn it into a function, you'd have to create a table variable and use that as a parameter. Then, any routine that wants to call the function has to build and populate the #temp table, then pass it in to the function.

Like I said, it gets pretty complex. To get things done quickly, I'd go with @valexhome's answer, and worry about updating/upgradng it later when the need arises.